# Creating my own portfolio custom-type

Tags: custom-post-types, gallery

I'm using WordPress to build my photography portfolio. So far I've created a *Custom Post Type* called `session` for each photo session, and I've managed to list all the sessions with each thumbnail in the home page.

Now, however, I have to create the content of each `session`. I'd like to keep it simple:

- The title
- A small description (if any).
- A set of pictures, that should appear straightaway in the post.

The problem is that I don't know how to face the inclusion of the images. Looks like using a *gallery* is not what I'm looking for, because it generates a set of thumbnails, and I just want the images in full size in the post.

What's the best way of doing this? The ideal case would be to have something like `the_images_of_this_post()` so I could place them at will from the template file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attachments are post objects, with `post_parent` set to the ID of the post they belong to (ie your 'session'). The WP Codex page on `wp_get_attachment_image()` has an example almost exactly like what you're trying to do: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image#Display_all_images_as_a_list Make sure that you replace the `post_parent` parameter in that example with the ID of the current session (which will probably be `get_the_ID()`, though it depends on how your loop works).